# Chropath for selenium xpath is not working?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, chropath

I installed chropath to finding out the xpath for websites.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='User ID']")
username.send_keys("abcc")
```

I wanted to find username xpath using chropath and it gave me `//input[@placeholder='User ID']` but it is still giving me `NoSuchElementException` error. I thought chropath extension would always give me correct xpath. 
What can be the reason for this ?

This is the code that I get when I inspect Username

```
<input type="text" placeholder="User ID" autocorrect="off" maxlength="6" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="characters" animate="true" label="" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8" xpath="1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, [chropath](/questions/tagged/chropath) was correct to find the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) for the desired element. However as the element is having the attribute `animate="true"`, when the element recieves the cursor **focus** the attribute `placeholder="User ID"` gets changed as a result [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is unable to locate the element.

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* within the **User ID** field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://kite.zerodha.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='User ID']//following-sibling::input[1]"))).send_keys("TANMAY")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://kite.zerodha.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.su-input-label.su-dynamic-label + input"))).send_keys("TANMAY")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: zerodha]

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB. You can also generate xpath in ChroPath using static attribute.
1. Click on setting icon available in ChroPath tab
2. In attribute name box, type attribute value & hit enter
3. It will generate xpath with given attribute if that will be unique else will try with other attribute.
4. If given attribute is not there for element, it will generate xpath with other attr.
5. Also for few attr sort cuts have been provided. If you don't want to generate xpath with them, uncheck them.

Comment: @SanjayKumarIChroPathCreator Great news, though I haven't used [tag:chropath] personally but I am aware _Chropath_ have made life a lot easier for software professionals using XPath. Thanks for the innovative approach.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and I think it is correct, however, I think you might be missing a `.click()` element. To make sure that the elements are present you could do the following, where I've added optional wait time for elements to be loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Handle wait time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='User ID']")))
username.click()
username.send_keys("abcc")
```